# Using my own model with GWT

Tags: gwt, model

I want to use my own existing model in GWT application. From what I've seen, GWT requests that model is placed in the ...gwt.client folder or one of its subfolders. However, my folder is in .jar file in the WebContent/lib folder of my project.

I've tried including my project by placing this line in MyModule.gwt.xml:

```
<source path="my.classpath.to.model.package" />
```

...however it seems that GWT is not aware of my .jar file during compile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the following: the jar file in your lib directory contains java sources, has a gwt.xml file, has a client folder next to the gwt.xml file and is for the client side of your project.

Add the line `<inherits name='my.classpath.to.model.package.MyModule' />` to your main module and make sure the lib directory is added to the compilation path.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that GWT Java->.js compiler needs .java files!